# Incorrect calculation of mathematical equation in Assembly Language (Intel)

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, microprocessors, x86-16

I have an equation that I want to model in Assembly language. I wrote the following code which is syntactically correct but producing wrong results in register. Final result is to be stored in *DX* register. The equation I am modeling is:

> *DX* = (*AX*<sup>2</sup> + (*AX*-1) + 2 * (*AX*+2)) / 2

Following is the code in assembly language for Intel microprocessor:

```
[org 0x0100]
            jmp start

number:         db  02
multiplicand:   db  0
multiplier:     db  0
multiResult:    dw  0
squareResult:   dd  0


square:     mov   [multiplicand], AX
            mov   [multiplier], AX
            call  multi
            mov   AX, [multiResult]
            mov   [squareResult], AX
            ret


multi:          mov CL, 8
                mov BX, [multiplicand]
                mov DX, [multiplier]

carryCheck:     shr BX, 1
                jnc skip

                 add    [multiResult], BX


skip:           shl BX, 1
                dec CL
                jnz carryCheck
                ret


start:          mov AX, [number]
                call    square
                mov DX, [squareResult]
                sub byte[number], 1
                add DX, AX
                add byte[number], 2
                mov AX, [number]
                mov [multiplicand],AX
                mov byte[multiplier], 2
                call    multi
                add DX, [multiResult]
                shr DX, 1                   ; division by 2

            mov AX, 0x4c00              ;ending program
            int 0x21
```

Comment: When you use a debugger to step through the code can you not determine the place where it fails?

Comment: You only have `db` byte storage but reading and writing `AX` and other 16-bit registers: collision. `db` ==> `dw`.

Comment: Why dont you use commenting in your assembly code?

Comment: @WeatherVane should I use all dw's?

Comment: What happened to `DX` the m.s word of the `square` calculation? You have, after all, allocated 4 bytes storage.

Comment: `multi` must use `multiplier` (`DX`) in some way.

Comment: what is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

You are making this *way* too complicated.  First, simplify the expression to one that's easier to compute

```
(AX*AX + (AX-1) + 2 * (AX+2)) / 2;
(AX*AX + AX + 2*AX - 1 + 2) / 2
(AX*AX + 3*AX + 1) / 2
(AX*(AX+3) + 1) / 2
```

That's easy and straightforward to implement:

```
mov   dx, ax
add   dx, 3      ; dx = ax+3

mul   dx         ; dx:ax = ax * (ax+3)

inc   ax         ; ignore the high-half of the mul result in DX.
shr   ax, 1

mov   dx, ax     ; apparently you want the result in DX?
```

Or are you supposed to keep 32-bit temporaries?  If so, use ADD/ADC to add 1 to DX:AX.  If you're using emu8086 or something, then you can't use SHRD to shift a bit from DX into AX.  So you could use SHR to shift a bit out of DX, and RCR to shift that bit into AX.

You'd also need to save the carry-out from AX+3 if you do it this way.

---

BTW, you can easily ask a compiler for ideas.  gcc doesn't really do pure 16-bit, though, and with 32-bit `unsigned` compiling in 32-bit mode, it uses LEA in ways that 16-bit addressing modes don't support.  But here's [what I tried on Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'unsigned+foo(unsigned+AX)+%7B%0A++unsigned+DX+%3D+(AX*AX+%2B+(AX-1)+%2B+2+*+(AX%2B2))+/+2%3B%0A++return+DX%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+bar(unsigned+AX)+%7B%0A++unsigned+DX+%3D+(AX*(AX%2B3)+%2B+1)+/+2%3B%0A++return+DX%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-m32'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

---

If you want to fix your original code, use a debugger.  IDK why you're branching on anything, or using memory for anything, and there are no comments.

Answer (score 0):

At the `carryCheck:` label, the instruction `shr BX, 1` should be `shr DX, 1`.

Comment: As noted in the comments by Weather Vane, there is also the potential for variable mangling, when word values are written into addresses with byte spaced labels. The code (as written) writes the correct values into the addresses, but if the order of the two `mov` instructions at the `square:` label were reversed, the result would be incorrect).